# How to reuse function and update corresponding data model instance?

Tags: swift, oop

In my code I have 5 separate instances of the same object and each of them are updated in a function. These functions are repeat the same code except they update the corresponding instance variables. Given that they follow the same logic but update different instance variables, do I have a more elegant option rather than to reimplement the function and modify the object model updating lines to the corresponding model?

This is what the structure is like:

```
var model1: MyObject = MyObject()
var stateOfModel1: StateObj = .empty
var model2: MyObject = MyObject()
var stateOfModel2: StateObj = .empty

functionForModel1(){
    stateOfModel1 = .new_state
    //other reused lines of code
    model1.attr1 = newAtrrVal
}
```

I'll have a very similar function for model 2 as well. If I can somehow build 1 function and update the corresponding variables, I can reduce the lines of code and wanted to know what my options would be.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you want to store this function, but you could create a class with a function as follows

```
func updateModel(model: inout MyObject, state: StateObj) {
    state = .newState
    // more code
    model.attr1 = newAttributeValue
}
```

Call the function as follows:

```
self.updateModel(model: &model1, state: &modelState1)
```

Some OOP principles

Comment: For Swift specifically, `func updateObj(obj: inout Obj, newAttr: String)` is the function signature to make parameter reference and calling the function goes as such: `updateObj(obj: &obj1, newAttr: "World")`. Although I'm not sure if the function needs to be `static` as my current functions aren't since 1 instance of the parent object has multiple instances of the child object

Comment: Yeah, you would call the function by `updateModel(for: model1, withState: stateOfModel1)`.  Also, it would be `func updateObj(obj inout: Obj, newAttr: String)` (check the location of the colon).